# c# indexer for list of list

Tags: c#, list, indexing

hi all 
i want to make an indexer to list of list to get items like this     myopj[i,j] .
my data structure is like this :

```
list<list<doubl>>
```

i try code like this but it not work

```
public double this[int r, int c] 
   {
     set 
       {
         if (this.list1.Count == 0 )

                {

                    this.list1[r].Add(value);

                }

         else

                  this.list1[r][c]=value;
       } 
   }
```

when i watch it the program don't enter the 'if' and it end the watch .

please is there anyone can help

and thank for all .

Comment: I guess `list1.Capacity` did not equal 0.

Comment: What class did you add `this` method to?

Comment: i try the list1.count but it's don't work 
the program don't check the if statment it's abrot

Comment: In your code you show us a set, yet you talk about get?

Comment: there is a get but it isn't here i'm sorry

Answer (score 2):

You should be checking the count, not the capacity. [Capacity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y52x03h2.aspx) is the number of elements the list can have, the [Count](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5s3kzhec.aspx) is the actual number of items in your list.
So, given a list that is not null, the capacity should NEVER be zero, but the count could be.

Answer (score 2):

It seems rather strange that your `value` is either a `list<T>` or a `T`.

Without more information, I suggest you implement this using a single, long list of T.
You will then translate `myList<T>[i,j]` to the underlying `list<T>[ i * numRows + j]`.

Sprinkle validations as required.

If you really, really must use lists of lists figure out if you want to end up with a rectangular matrix (i.e. the list at row `i` has the same number of elements as the list at row `j`), or a staggered array (where each list has an independent number of elements).
If you're in the first case, consider creating and filling the row lists automatically, with the appropriate number of elements( use `default<T>` to initialize them)

Update:

Then, if what you really need is a rectangular matrix then use a list.
It will have numRows * numColumns elements. 
Imagine that, instead of putting one row under the other to make a matrix, you put the elements of a row one after the other.

So, if you have:
11 12 13
21 22 23
31 32 33

in a list form they will be
11 12 13 21 22 23 31 32 33

There is a simple conversion between the X and Y (or i and j) coordinates in the first form and the index in the list in the second form.

Comment: thank you, i want to make a matrix class it's maybe rectangular or staggered i don't know any thing more powerful than list of list but i want an indexer to make some process more easy 
thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You want the length property, and not Capactiy.

Use:

```
 if (this.list1.Count < r )
```

Your algorithm doesn't really make much sense, you might want to describe what you are trying to accomplish. It looks like you are trying to make it grow if its not large enough, but the logic in the two seperate paths(if else) doesn't align.

Comment: ok i'm sorry about (if else ) but in my code its ok the proplem is my program don't check the if statment it's go directly to end of the program and the dispose function ...

Comment: The if statement is in a set, please post code on what you are trying to set, or the show us the magical program code you are referring to.

Comment: i put this code under set accessor
if (this.matrixData.Count==0) {

List<double> col = new List<double>();

col.Add(value);

this.matrixData.Add(col);

this.Height ++ ;

this.Width ++ ;
}

else if (c == this.Width+1 )
{

List<double> col = new List<double>();

col.Add(value);

this.matrixData.Add(col);

this.Width ++ ;
}

else if (r == this.Height+1)

{
this.matrixData[c-1].Add(value);
this.Height ++ ;
}

else if (c == this.Width && this.matrixData[c-1].Count < r )

{
this.matrixData[c-1].Add(value);
}

else this.matrixData[r-1][c-1]=value;

Answer (score 1):

Why are you checking the capacity? It will likely never be zero. Did you mean to check the `Count`?